# How to get a list of all connected Android devices, using the command line on a Mac

Tags: android, macos, shell, command-line

I need to pull up a list of all Android devices connected to a Mac computer, using the command-line. The Mac is running Yosemite. Any shell script would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: can you please try getting a list of USB connected devices first?

Comment: Not all are connected through USB, that's the problem

Comment: are you unable to use adb?  `adb devices` will list all devices

Answer (score 5):

if you need show connected devices, first check android debug is enabled and then in your command line, run `adb devices`.